# Inserting tikzpicture at multiple places

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm new to using Latex and tikzpicture. I've a piece of code as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

% horizontal axis
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[anchor=north] {$z$};

% labels
\draw   (0,0) node[anchor=north] {0}
    (2,0) node[anchor=north] {20}
    (2.5,0) node[anchor=north] {25}
    (8,0) node[anchor=north] {80}
    (8.5,0) node[anchor=north] {85};

 % vertical axis
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3) node[anchor=east] {$K$};
\draw   (0,0) node[anchor=east] {0}
    (0,2) node[anchor=east] {1};

\draw[thick] (2,0) -- (2.5,2) -- (8,2) -- (8.5,0);

\draw[thick,dashed] (2.5,0) -- (2.5,2);
\draw[thick,dashed] (8.,0) -- (8.0,2);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to use the above picture at multiple places in my document. How do I reference this picture in my main code. Something like this:

```
%% Call the above picture at coordinate (6,0)

%%% Some text %%%%

%% call the above picture at coordinate (12,-3) and (12, -9)
```

How to do something like this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What precisely is the picture you'd like to repeat? The full thing or some part of it?

Comment: In general you can store rendered/typeset content into a "savebox" and use it multiple times. This freezes all settings but only processes the content once. `\newbox\mysavebox` and then `\sbox\mysavebox{<content>}` to save and `\usebox\mysavebox` to use. For larger content there is the `{lrbox}{\mysavebox}` environment. For placing the box at different coordinates create another tikzpicture and place the box using a node.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Answer (score 7):

You can define a new pic using style like `mydrawing/.pic={...}`. And then use it like a `node`. Here is concrete example :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  mydrawing/.pic = {
    % horizontal axis
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[anchor=north] {$z$};
    % labels
    \draw
        (0,0) node[anchor=north] {0}
        (2,0) node[anchor=north] {20}
        (2.5,0) node[anchor=north] {25}
        (8,0) node[anchor=north] {80}
        (8.5,0) node[anchor=north] {85};
     % vertical axis
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3) node[anchor=east] {$K$};
    \draw
      (0,0) node[anchor=east] {0}
      (0,2) node[anchor=east] {1};
    \draw[thick] (2,0) -- (2.5,2) -- (8,2) -- (8.5,0);
    \draw[thick,dashed] (2.5,0) -- (2.5,2);
    \draw[thick,dashed] (8.,0) -- (8.0,2);
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (0,0) {mydrawing};
    \pic[scale=0.7] at (12,-3) {mydrawing};
    \pic[red] at (12,-9) {mydrawing};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just put in a `\newcommand` all the drawing part:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\mypic[1]{
% horizontal axis
\draw[->] #1 -- ($#1+(10,0)$) node[anchor=north] {$z$};

% labels
\draw   #1 node[anchor=north] {0}
    ($#1+(2,0)$) node[anchor=north] {20}
    ($#1+(2.5,0)$) node[anchor=north] {25}
    ($#1+(8,0)$) node[anchor=north] {80}
    ($#1+(8.5,0)$) node[anchor=north] {85};

 % vertical axis
\draw[->] ($#1+(0,0)$) -- ($#1+(0,3)$) node[anchor=east] {$K$};
\draw   #1 node[anchor=east] {0}
    ($#1+(0,2)$) node[anchor=east] {1};

\draw[thick] ($#1+(2,0)$) -- ($#1+(2.5,2)$) -- ($#1+(8,2)$) -- ($#1+(8.5,0)$);

\draw[thick,dashed] ($#1+(2.5,0)$) -- ($#1+(2.5,2)$);
\draw[thick,dashed] ($#1+(8.,0)$) -- ($#1+(8.0,2)$);
}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\mypic{(0,0)}
\mypic{(12,-3)}
\mypic{(12,-9)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Nested tikzpictures are not really advisable, so I left the `\begin` and `\end{tikzpicture}` out of my command

I also had to use "relative coordinates" with the help of `calc` library.

Comment: Just wondering if you want to switch to `\begin{scope}[shift=#1]` ... `\end{scope}` instead of shifting all the coordinates one by one...

Comment: How do I increase and decrease the size of the picture?

Comment: @johndaniel You may play with `scale`, which is set to `0.7` right after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.